# react-native metro bundle stuck and not running progress bar

Tags: react-native

I work on react-native project on IOS & ANDROID.

On IOS the metro bundler console stuck at

```
Metro Bundler ready.
Loading dependency graph, done.
```

Nothing happen even after long delay. It should do the following :

```
Metro Bundler ready.
Loading dependency graph, done.
BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.android.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0%       (0/1)Launching Dev Tools...
BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.android.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (982/982), done.
BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.android.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.
```

Any idea please ?

I try to remove node_modules , clean project via Xcode , run "npm start"

Comment: edit connecting computer and mobile on same wifi network solve also this kind of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way to make it work.
the project i work on was started a year and a half ago with xcode 9. xcode 10 change the way to process the compilation.
you can configure it to use the xcode 9 legacy way ( i don't know the bad side of this )

```
 In Xcode -> file -> project setting 

 for  "pre user projects settings" choose "legacy build system"
```

[image]

EDIT : connecting the phone and computer to same wifi make it work too  ( or create a hotspot with laptop)

Answer (score 3):

I have this sentence under scripts on my package.json. Try run it using `npm run clear-all`.

```
"clear-all": "watchman watch-del-all; rm -rf ./ios/build;  rm -rf ./ios/Pods; rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*;rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; rm -rf node_modules/; npm cache verify; npm install; npm start --reset-cache"
```

after that you have to run `pod install` and `react-native run-ios` again. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks for help. i run the clear-all ( removed watcham cmd because i dont use it) . i dont use pod too,  not installed on my mac.

Comment: it make me error in node-modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4, c compiler cannot create executables. i had to run " cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/ && ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh" then remove and re add libfishhook.a

Comment: but the problem is here, nothing happen after metro Loading dependency graph, done.